# Imap_email - send php variables in message

Tags: php

I'm send an email for a user, i make a query:

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$emailDestinatario'");
if($consulta === FALSE) {
(header('Location: http://l2prime.org/index.php?login=success') xor die(mysql_error()));
}    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
{
    $username = $row['username'];
}
}
```

Then i have the $body that's the variable for the body message on email:

```
$body = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Recuperação de password.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Dear <?php echo $username?>,</h3>
<p>
<b>Some text here.</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
';
```

That's `<?php echo $username?>` doesn't work, the email arrives "Dear ,", no username at all.
Could anyone help me in this one?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Marcelo

Comment: You should look into sql injection...

Comment: can you give me some more information about it?
Some goog article perhapes?

Comment: Well, it isn't related to your problem, but depending on the input sanitation you are doing(or not doing) your code is open to sql injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its pretty obvious

```
$body = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Recuperação de password.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Dear '.$username.',</h3>
<p>
<b>Some text here.</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
';
```

also you could have something like this:

```
$body = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Recuperação de password.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Dear VARIABLE_USERNAME,</h3>
<p>
<b>Some text here.
Regards,
VARIABLE_SITE_NAME
</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
';
```

and then you could replace the VARIABLE_USERNAME and VARIABLE_SITE_NAME and other VARIABLE_XXXXXX with appropriate values:

```
$body = str_replace("VARIABLE_USERNAME",$username,$body);
$body = str_replace("VARIABLE_SITE_NAME",$site_name,$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `<?php` again in the script. It should be:

```
$body = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Recuperação de password.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Dear '. strip_tags($username) .',</h3>
<p>
<b>Some text here.</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
';
```

So, if `$username = "foo";`, it will output:

```
Dear foo,

Some text here.
```

strip_tags function will strip out HTML / PHP tags from a given string. It's *safer*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I apreciated your answer! Thanks for sharing it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<<<EOF:`

```
$body = <<<EOF
Something Something {$var} Something Something
Something Something 
Something Something Something {$var2}
EOF;
```

P.S. Why is everybody so worried with SQL injection here? He just wants to send an e-mail, not  to query a database..